# Trying to visit /js/app.js net::ERR_ABORTED 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: laravel, vue.js

My problem isn't easy to describe, i guess I forgot something obvious but I just can't figure out what..

Here is the error: GET http://127.0.0.1/ideayear/850/js/app.js net::ERR_ABORTED 500 (Internal Server Error)

And here is the problem:

Until now I had

in web.php

```
Route::get('idea/{n}', 'IdeaController@idea')->name('idea');
```

And I want to add the year

```
Route::get('ideayear/{n}/{m}', 'IdeaController@idea')->name('idea');


public function idea($idea, $year){
    $idea = substr($idea, 0, strpos($idea, "-"));

    $sql =  " SELECT BLABLA  where year like ..."

    $array = DB::connection('ideas')->select( DB::connection('ideas')->raw($sql));


    return view('ideas/idea', ['idea' => json_encode($array), 'defyear' => $year] );
}
```

when I had public function idea($idea){} it worked well, but since I added $year, I get this strange issue when visiting http://127.0.0.1/ideayear/850/2018

Give me the error:
GET http://127.0.0.1/ideayear/850/js/app.js net::ERR_ABORTED 500 (Internal Server Error)

And I have absolutely no idea why it's for some reason trying to visit js/app.js

Here is idea.blade.php (in case if it helps)
@extends('template')

```
@section('contenu')
<div>
    <div id="app">
        <ideapage ideas="{{ $idea }}" defyear="{{ $defyear }}"></ideapage>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

[EDIT] Content of 
(I removed almost everything from IdeaPage.vue, same problem)

```
<template>
    <div> {{ideas}}
        {{defyear}}
    </div>
</template>


<script>

export default {
    props: {
        ideas: String,
        defyear: String
    }
}
</script>
```

Here is the error in laravel.log

```
#0 C:\\laragon\\www\\projet\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php(624): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->runQueryCallback(Object(Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Expression), Array, Object(Closure))
#1 C:\\laragon\\www\\projet\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php(333): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->run(Object(Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Expression), Array, Object(Closure))
#2 C:\\laragon\\www\\projet\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\IdeaController.php(121): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->select(Object(Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Expression))
#3 [internal function]: App\\Http\\Controllers\\IdeaController->idea('850', '', 'app.js')
#4 C:\\laragon\\www\\projet\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller.php(54): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#5 C:\\laragon\\www\\projet\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher.php(45): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction('idea', Array)
```

Why is it trying to visit idea('850', '', 'app.js')**  ? i really don't get this...

Comment: can you show us the template <ideapage></ideapage>

Comment: Check the latest content on your `storage/logs/laravel.log` file, there should be more specific information there, and if you find something post it here.

Comment: Thanks. I added the content of <ideapage> and the error to my main message:

#3 [internal function]: App\\Http\\Controllers\\IdeaController->idea('850', '', 'app.js')